# How to Send DateTime Or DbNull to DB using c#?

Tags: c#, database, datetime, null

I have a web form (.aspx) that has a textbox.
My user can enter a value into the textbox as a persian date.
what should I do is converting texbox.text into DateTime.
But sometimes,the textbox has no text within it and so I should take care of it and return null.

when I return null how can I insert null (c#) into DB?

Comment: what technology are you using? DataSets? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4):

It all depend on how you are doing your data access.. by hand?

If so; there are two common ways of passing a null `DateTime` around; the original was to use `DateTime.MinValue` to mean `null`; the second is to use `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka `DateTime?`) to pass the date around. Then in your DAL you detect this and switch to `DBNull.Value`:

```
if(someDate == DateTime.MinValue) { // or "== null" for Nullable<DateTime>
    dateParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    dateParm.Value = someDate;
}
```

With LINQ-to-SQL, the `Nullable<DateTime>` approach should "just work".